# How to access Context to create a file directory in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am using this createDir() function to create directories but to call it from Composable functions I need to take function outside of MainActivity unfortunately because of applicationContext it does not work.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

   fun createDir() {

       val path = applicationContext.filesDir
       val letDirectory = File(path, "TestDir")
       val resultMkdirs: Boolean = letDirectory.mkdirs()
   }

   ...
}
```

This is what I want to do.

```
fun createDir() {

    val path = applicationContext.filesDir
    val letDirectory = File(path, "TestDir")
    val resultMkdirs: Boolean = letDirectory.mkdirs()
}



@Composable
fun someFunction() {

     ...        

     Button(
        onClick = {
            createDir()
        }   
      ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `LocalContext`?

```
LocalContext.current
```

Your modified code:

```
fun createDir(context: Context){

    val path = context.filesDir
    val letDirectory = File(path, "TestDir")
    val resultMkdirs: Boolean = letDirectory.mkdirs()

}



@Composable
fun someFunction() {

    ...        
  
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Button(
      onClick = {
          createDir(context)
      }   
    ) { ... }
```